# Boot Image from Running Ubuntu

Tags: configuration, backup, restore

I have a Linux system running in another place, which I use as processing server. Now I'm acquiring a new one and I would like to export all the configuration programs and maybe folder structure to the new one.

However I can't access it physically.

I would like to know if there is a way of downloading or creating a boot image to install on my new device directly from the running device, via SCP or something like that.

If that isn't posible, what are your suggestions to export the configuration to the new computer?

Comment: Can someone else get physical access to the computer? In that case that person could boot into a live Clonezilla system and make a 'Clonezilla image' of the server. -- It might be impossible to get a good image of a running system (because some files closely connected to the operating system will be modified during the copying process). But it should be possible to copy the `/home` directory and several system settings, for example from `/etc`, and this way make it easier to get a new system that is similar.

Comment: No, not really, copying /home and /etc may be enough. Thanks

Comment: It's reasonably easy *if* you have the root filesystem on LVM (or on a filesystem that allows snapshots). Then you can ensure the root fs is quiescent, take a snapshot and backup from that. (The boot filesystem can be separate and does not have to be on LVM.)

It is possible (but not trivial) to move an existing non-LVM root/boot filesystem onto 2 separate filesystems, one (for boot) non-LVM and the other (for root) on LVM.

Comment: `ssh user@host 'sudo tar czvf - /' > backup.tgz` like you said, if you just need the files themselves, and can reasonably manually restore things, this may satisfy. a more reliable "restorable" snapshot would be if you could go and `dd bs=1M /dev/sda1 | gzip - | ssh user@host 'cat - > backup_hd.tgz'` thus backing up the entire partition that `/` is mounted on.  but it doesn't sound like that works here. nothing you can do reliably without being able to directly access the volume in a powered off state.